# The meaning of "to"

Tags: meaning

I'm confused about the meaning of "to" in below sentence:

> Despite heavy use of pesticides, significant losses **to** diseases and insect pests are sustained each year.

I'm not sure whether it means "because", since I never use it in this way.

Is there any example with similar usage?

Thanks!

Comment: Better would be "due to" or "attributed to".

Comment: Where did you see this citation? It could be a typo. I'm inclined to agree with @DavidCarraher that **due to** makes more sense.

Comment: @David Carraher As JEL says, 'losses to [thing causing the loss]' is quite acceptable. It mirrors the 'City lost to United' usage.

Comment: Mistranslation ?http://www.zybang.com/question/d60eb545a9c01487bd4576708cfb148d.html

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Translation, in my opinion. 'Losses to insect pests' is probably best considered a personification of 'losses to the [advancing] enemy [troops]', though the usage probably doesn't usually trigger the thought. And 'losses due to the advancing enemy troops' is not as  idiomatic as the _due_-less version, and is less incisive.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Again, I have to disagree (though I'm not sure why you're informing just me that you think it a duplicate). That question just assumes that the construction is correct. It asks rather about possible modifiers of 'losses', not asking about the function / appropriateness of 'to'. And the function / appropriateness of 'to' are not mentioned in the answers/

Comment: I'll hazard a guess here, the linked page in Chinese (?) that contains the version with *to* is a website that helps candidates take the GRE exam. The clue is the number 100 written in red, I don't know if the exam is marked out of a 100 but it could well be. Until we know who wrote the excerpt, and what it says,  I say this question is too localized.

Comment: @Mari-LouA That page is someone asking about the meaning of _yet despite_ in the sentence (which is question 8 on page 80 in the second edition of the Official Guide to, I’m guessing, the GRE test from the linked question). I don’t think there’s any mistranslation to it, incidentally. It sounds perfectly natural to me—more natural than _due to_ would. You sustain a loss _to_ someone/something.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I bow to your expertise but to have/bear a loss *to* something, is very unusual, I would have said "because of" And btw there is a typo in the OP's example **insect pets**, it should be **pests**, but at this point who knows!

Comment: @Mari-LouA With _have/bear_, yes, quite unusual. With _suffer/sustain_, it's the norm I'd say, and even more so with the verb _lose_ itself. You don't lose someone due to/because of cancer, you lose them to cancer.

Comment: Deleted link to previous question which does contain the preposition "to", which, for some reason, I hadn't seen. So, apologies to the OP. I'm sorry for making such a fuss. EDIT @JanusBahsJacquet I like your explanation a lot, that does help me!

Comment: Sorry, that's my typo.  It should be "pests" instead of "pets".   And this is a sentence in GRE Official Guide.

Answer (score 2):

The use of "losses to [causal agent]" is common, and will be readily understood by most speakers of English.

Other examples:

> 1954   Jrnl. Operations Res. Soc. Amer. 2 10   The actual figures were used from World War II campaigns for forces dispatched, aborts, losses to enemy aircraft and ground fire, operational losses, [etc.].

(From the cited source; quote via the [OED](http://oed.com/).)

> There are certainly more losses to diseases and pests today....

(From ["Putting the Hive back to Mother Natures Height"](http://americasbeekeeper.org/Hive_Height.htm).)

The cursory research I completed suggests the uses are most common with reference to agricultural and husbandry losses, but as the first quote (above) suggests, the uses are by no means restricted to such losses.

### Edit

Further research reveals that the construction is also common with reference to military losses, as suggested by Edwin Ashworth in the comments on your question *and by* the first quote I give above.

Answer (score -2):

You might replace losses to diseases and insect pests" by "losses due to diseases and insect pests". This use of "to", though understandable, is a bit unusual in my view. It is not registered in Longman DCE, to, preposition, number 1-22.
http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/to_2

Comment: It’s not unusual at all to suffer/sustain a loss to something like a disease. It is perhaps more common to use _lose_ the verb (“We lost her to cancer”) than _loss_ the noun, but the two share many properties, not least their affinity with the preposition _to_.